# How do I fix incorrect label placement?

Tags: labels, circuitikz

The latest version of `circuitikz` `(1.3.2)` displaces the label to the source of the component.  I tried using `[=v1.2.1]` to fix it but it does not work.  Any ideas?

Here is the issue:

[image]

Here follows my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}[style={european resistor, resistors/scale=0.55, inductors/scale=0.55, electromechanicals/scale=0.6, blocks/scale=0.5, grounds/scale=0.55},=v1.2.1]

\begin{document}
{\small\begin{circuitikz}
     % LV Winding
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
{\draw (a)
    node {x} %debug
    ++(-5,-1) node [anchor=east] {$n$} 
    to [L,name=n,-,l=$L_{nn}$] 
    +(5,0) node [anchor=north] {};
    }
\end{circuitikz}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If you change the `+(5,0)` to `++(5,0)` it works. The `+(5,0)` is a "just once" movement, so the terminal point is reset midway. I do not know how (and if) I can fix it.

Comment: PS the `[style=.... ]` thing is not supported --- just use a `\ctikzset` in the preamble.

Comment: I copied that from the `\begin{circuitikz}[style=...]` my bad!

Comment: (will be) Fixed in 1.4.1 : https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/570

Comment: v1.4.1 has been sent to CTAN, it should arrive in a couple of days. https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/releases

Answer (score 3):

First of all, notice that that `style=...` in the extended option of the `\usepackage` is not supported (where do you saw that?) and that the `[=v1.1.2]` rollback works only from version `1.4.0` upward.

Anyway, the problem seems to be the "once relative" movement `+(5,0)`. Everything is ok with `++(5,0)`. A bit of research using the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}[=v0.8.3]

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to [L,l=$L_{nn}$] +(5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

shows that the problem started between 0.7 and 0.8.3. (between 0.7 and 0.8, to be exact. Let's go bisecting).

The bug (a relative movement internal to the `to path` command to set the label distance) was there since `v0.8`, but it has been masked by the underlying Ti*k*Z until it went visible with Ti*k*Z version `3.1.8` --- this is why you can see no problem in overleaf, which is using Ti*k*Z `3.1.5b` today (July 11, 2021). It will be fixed for both old and new Ti*k*Z starting from `circuitikz` version `1.4.1`.

For now, you can use:

```latex
\draw (0,0) node {x} %debug
    ++(-5,-1) node [anchor=east] {$n$}
    coordinate(a) to [L,name=n,-,l=$L_{nn}$]
    ++(5,0) (a) node [anchor=north] {$y$};
```

as a workaround.

Comment: It is working on the current 2020 overleaf distribution.  That is why I reported it for the new distribution.

Comment: Ah! So this is the change in Ti*k*Z that changed the `to[] +(x)` thing... can't find the commit now.

Comment: Found a way to fix it. Stay tuned.

Comment: The MWE works in overleaf and fails in texlive2021.

Comment: Fix works.  When will this be available on TexLive?